# как вывести треугольник Паскаля на Python?

Tags: python

Написал такой код:

```
def pascal(primary, deep=10):
    if deep == 1:
        new_list = [primary]
    elif deep == 2:
        new_list = []
        for i in range (deep):
            new_list.extend(pascal(primary, 1))
    else:
        new_list = []
        for i in range(0,deep):
            if i == 0 or i == deep-1:
                new_list.append(primary)
            else:
                new_list.append(pascal(primary, deep-1)[i-1]+pascal(primary, deep-1)[i])
    print(new_list)
    return new_list

pascal(1)
```

Вместо треугольника Паскаля выводит следующее:

```
[1]   
[1]    
[1, 1]   
[1]    
[1]    
[1, 1]    
[1, 2, 1]
```

В чём ошибка и как исправить?

Comment: В треугольнике Паскаля вычисления несколько сложнее: https://parg.co/8e4

Comment: @Sheridan, в смысле сложнее? Наоборот, все проще вычисляется.

Answer (score 5):

Простейшая реализация:

```
def PrintPasTriangle(rows):
    row = [1]
    for i in range(rows):
        print(row)
        row = [sum(x) for x in zip([0]+row, row+[0])]
        
PrintPasTriangle(10)
```

Вывод:

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 3, 1]
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
[1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]
[1, 6, 15, 20, 15, 6, 1]
[1, 7, 21, 35, 35, 21, 7, 1]
[1, 8, 28, 56, 70, 56, 28, 8, 1]
[1, 9, 36, 84, 126, 126, 84, 36, 9, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Простая итеративная реализация (каждый следующий ряд вычисляется из предыдущего, без факториалов, без рекурсии):

```
def next_row(row):
    row = [1] + row
    for i in range(1, len(row)-1):
        row[i] += row[i+1]
    return row

row = []

for i in range(10):
    row = next_row(row)
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваша функция работает и правильно вычисляет строки.
Трудности возникают при их печати.

---

Дело в том, что Ваша функция очень неоптимизированная.
Она вызывается с одинаковыми аргументами огромное количество раз.

Сложность Вашего алгоритма — O(2^N).

Всё это я говорю к тому, что, при каждом вызове функции, исполняется печать возвращаемого значения, а значит будет исполняться печатать и в служебных вызовах:

```py
[1]        # Служебный вызов! (Напечаталось при расчёте pascal(2))
[1]        # Служебный вызов! (Напечаталось при расчёте pascal(2))
[1, 1]
[1]        # Служебный вызов! (Напечаталось при расчёте pascal(3))
[1]        # Служебный вызов! (Напечаталось при расчёте pascal(3))
[1, 1]     # Служебный вызов! (Напечаталось при расчёте pascal(3))
[1, 2, 1]
```

Есть несколько способов отменить печать тех значений, которые нам не нужны:

- Кэшировать возвращаемые значения, от чего не будет исполняться функция (следовательно и служебная печать).
- Переписать алгоритм динамически.
- Добавить служебный аргумент (например, `tmp`) и использовать его как флаг. Но это ужасно некрасиво и к тому же очень сложно сделать. Не будем рассматривать этот способ.

---

Кэширование можно реализовать с помощью следующего декоратора:
[`@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=100, typed=False)`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache)

***Пример с кэшированием:***

```py
from functools import lru_cache


@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def pascal(...):
    ...
```

---

***Моя динамическая реализация:***

```py
def get_pascal_triangle(deep: int) -> list:
    row_0 = [1]
    row_1 = [1, 1]
    triangle = [row_0] + [row_1] + [[1] + [1]*i for i in range(2, deep + 1)]

    for i in range(2, len(triangle)):
        for j in range(1, len(triangle[i]) - 1):
            triangle[i][j] = triangle[i-1][j-1] + triangle[i-1][j]
    return triangle
```

Она довольно наивна и тоже считает некоторые значения несколько раз, но это уже намного лучше, чем рекурсия.

---

**UPD:**

***Хорошая и оптимизированная реализация:***

```py
def get_pascal_triangle(rows):
    def combination(n, r):
        return int((math.factorial(n)) / ((math.factorial(r)) * math.factorial(n - r)))

    result = []
    for count in range(rows):
        row = []
        for element in range(count + 1): 
            row.append(combination(count, element))
        result.append(row)
    return result
```

---

Две последние реализации не печатают отдельные строки, а возвращают список всех строк сразу.
Чтобы распечатать треугольник, можете использовать этот код:

```py
result = get_pascal_triangle(...)
print(*result, sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def pascal_triangle(n):
    row = [1]
    y = [0]
    for x in range(max(n, 0)):
        if x < n:
            print((n-x)*" ",row)
        else:
            print(row)
        row = [left + right for left, right in zip(row + y, y + row)]


a = pascal_triangle(5)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Я решил данную задачу через словарь:

```
z={}
for i in range(16):
    y=[1] # единица есть во всех строках
    for k in range(1,i): # высчитываем значения текущей строки с помощью словаря, не учитывая единицы по краям
        y.append(int(z[i-1][k-1])+int(z[i-1][k]))
    if i>0: # данное условие применимо для всех строк, кроме первой
        y+=[1]
    z[i]=y

for k,v in z.items(): # в данном случае выводится вначале номер строки, а затем сама строка. Думаю, это наглядно
    print(k,v)
```

Результат:

```
0 [1]
1 [1, 1]
2 [1, 2, 1]
3 [1, 3, 3, 1]
4 [1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
5 [1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]
6 [1, 6, 15, 20, 15, 6, 1]
7 [1, 7, 21, 35, 35, 21, 7, 1]
8 [1, 8, 28, 56, 70, 56, 28, 8, 1]
9 [1, 9, 36, 84, 126, 126, 84, 36, 9, 1]
10 [1, 10, 45, 120, 210, 252, 210, 120, 45, 10, 1]
11 [1, 11, 55, 165, 330, 462, 462, 330, 165, 55, 11, 1]
12 [1, 12, 66, 220, 495, 792, 924, 792, 495, 220, 66, 12, 1]
13 [1, 13, 78, 286, 715, 1287, 1716, 1716, 1287, 715, 286, 78, 13, 1]
14 [1, 14, 91, 364, 1001, 2002, 3003, 3432, 3003, 2002, 1001, 364, 91, 14, 1]
15 [1, 15, 105, 455, 1365, 3003, 5005, 6435, 6435, 5005, 3003, 1365, 455, 105, 15, 1]
```